# Signed jar execution performance

Tags: java, jar, signed, jarsigner

When I execute a signed jar, it is very slow using 2GB of memory. The same jar not signed is very fast and uses 300MB of memory.

Is there any way to reduce the amount of memory used in executing a signed jar.
I used a plugin in the pom.xml to sign the jar.